# "to be more precise" vs. "to be more precisely"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

While proofreading the thesis of a colleague, I came across the phrase "to be more precisely" and corrected it to "to be more precise". I'm pretty sure that my correction is correct but I have trouble to justify my change. I think this is also because I'm not quite sure what the precise subject corresponding to "be" is. Is it the author, or the argumentation or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is the language that becomes more precise with more explanation, and only indirectly does the author. When you edit and come across a restatement that is more precise, ask yourself if you can remove the previous less-precise part, or if the first form helps the reader with a good start.

Comment: I suggest you proofread the title of your question.... ;)

Comment: @IanMacDonald Done! Couldn’t decide which order I prefer and obviously changed my mind after having written the first alternative :P

Comment: @YosefBaskin That’s convincing! In our subject (mathematics) such constructions are pretty common to distinguish between aim and mean, for example: “We show that the rationale function under consideration is well-defined. To be more precise, we show that the denominator is strictly positive.”

Comment: Without the complete sentence, it’s not possible to say.  “John used a micrometer because he assumed it to be more precisely calibrated.” “John used a micrometer to be more precise.”

Comment: @jim Whatever the context, " "to be more precisely" is not well-formed in English...

Comment: @Nico - So you don't believe “to be more precisely calibrated” is grammatical?

Comment: @jim Yes, you are absolutely right. I was thinking about the frequent prefab "to be more precise" in order to specify one's assertion. I hadn't thought about your example because the adjective is missing in the OP...